# Help understanding the proof for the infinity case of L' Hopital's Rule.

Tags: limits, proof-writing

I am trying to understand the infinity case of L'Hopital's rule. I got this proof from Folland's Advanced Calculus. That is, suppose $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions on $(a,b)$ and $\lim|f(x)|=\lim|g(x)|=\infty$. If $g'(x) \neq 0$ on (a,b) and the limit $\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L$, then for $g(x) \neq 0$ the limit $\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$.

The proof focuses on the left handed- case as $x \to a-$.
Given $\epsilon >0$, we wish to show that $|\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L|<\epsilon$ for when $x$ is sufficiently close to $a$ on the left. Since $\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\to L$ and $|g(x)| \to \infty$, we can choose $x_0<a$ so that

$|\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}-L|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x_0<x<a$.

Using the generalized Mean Value Theorem, if $x_0<x<a$ we get

$\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)-g(x_0}=\dfrac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$ for some $c \in (x_0,x)$. Since $x<x_0<a$ we get $|\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)-g(x_0}-L|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $x_0<x<a$.

Observe that, $\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)-g(x_0}=\dfrac{\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}-\dfrac{f(x_0)}{g(x)}}{1-\dfrac{g(x_0)}{g(x)}}$.

Then  $|g(x)| \to \infty$ as $x \to a$ means that $\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)-g(x_0)}=\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.
It follows that for $x$ sufficiently close to $a$ we have $|\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)-g(x_0)}-\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$. Thus, using the preceeding estimate we get $|\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L|<\epsilon$. $\square$

My questions regarding this proof is towards the bottom. Why is the line $|\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)-g(x_0)}-\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ needed and where does it come from? How did this lead to $|\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L|<\epsilon$?

Answer (score 1):

You use a triangle inequality:
$$
\left\vert\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - L\right\vert
\le 
\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)-f(x_0)}\right|
+
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)-f(x_0)} -L\right|
$$